# How to handle errors in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have a good question that it's hard for me to find the answer. Sometimes i get an error something like this:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'email'undefined"
    found in

    ---> <IUserSettings> at src\IUser\IUserSettings.vue
           <Imenu> at src\Imenu.vue
             <Icontent> at src\Icontent.vue
               <ISlider> at src\UI\slider\ISlider.vue
                 <ISetup> at src\ISetup.vue
                   <ISlider> at src\UI\slider\ISlider.vue
                     <Iaccess> at src\Iaccess.vue
                       <ISlider> at src\UI\slider\ISlider.vue
                         <App> at src\App.vue
                           <Root>
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
        at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js?{"id":"data-v-2e2bc539","hasScoped":true,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/IUser/IUserSettings.vue (app.js:6008), <anonymous>:159:63)
        at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.esm.js?efeb:4544)
        at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:2788)
        at Watcher.get (vue.esm.js?efeb:3142)
        at Watcher.run (vue.esm.js?efeb:3219)
        at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.esm.js?efeb:2981)
        at Array.eval (vue.esm.js?efeb:1837)
        at flushCallbacks (vue.esm.js?efeb:1758)
```

How do i find where the error come from? Is there away to to trace the tag where the error was occurred? Thx

Answer (score 0):

The error happens at the first element you see in the trace. In your example, it happens inside `src\IUser\IUserSettings.vue`. Look for an object which has `email` property in that element, and make sure it isn't `undefined`.

Comment: Hey thx, but it's not the case, i want to know where in IUserSettings.vue i get an error. For example i removed all email vars from my component but i still getting this error and i don't know from where.... This scenario i getting all the time in development and take me time to find out what tag is responsible for this error. It will be nice if Vue will show us the tag where error occured.

Comment: Interesting. Can you share that component here?

Comment: And if possible, its parent, src\Imenu.vue

Comment: I did find where the error occured, but it took me like 10 min to go through all 400 lines to find it. To fix the error is not the problem, the problem to find it. I think it's only the downside of Vue where you don't know where the error come from although it does show me the line number of error when it occurs in lifecycle.